# How to get the objects from a ArrayList <HashMap<String,String>>

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am following a tutorial to parse JSON objects. The tutorial defines:

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
```

and later it is adding each JSON object to the ArrayList:

```
                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_IDOBJETO, idObjeto);
                        contact.put(TAG_TITULO, titulo);
                        contact.put(TAG_DIRECCION, direccion);
                        contact.put(TAG_LATITUD, latitud);
                        contact.put(TAG_LONGITUD, longitud);
                        contact.put(TAG_PROCEDENCIA, procedencia);
                        contact.put(TAG_IMAGEN, imagen);
                        Log.e("REGISTRO ACTUAL",procedencia);
                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
```

I would now get the content of each object to create map makers, but I don't know how to do it. I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just reverse the process:

```
int i = ...;
HashMap<String,String> contact = contactList.get(i); // get the i-th contact
String idObjecto = contact.get(TAG_IDOBJECTO);
// etc.
```

To iterate through the results in `onPostExecute` and create the markers:

```
protected void onPostExecute(...) {
    for (HashMap<String,String> contact : contactList) {
        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .title(contact.get(TAG_TITULO))
             .position(new LatLng(
                 Double.parseDouble(contact.get(TAG_LATITUD)),
                 Double.parseDouble(contact.get(TAG_LONGITUD))
             ))
             // etc.
        );
        // do something with the marker
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for yor answer. Would you mind helping me creating the needed iteration at the onPostExecute method from the JSON parsing process to get all objects data to create the markers?

Comment: I really appreciate it, you have made my day, I have been looking for this for all the day long. Thank you very very much.